# Retrieve "filename" from gcp storage during dbt-external-tables sideload?

Tags: google-bigquery, external-tables, dbt

I have a simple 9 column report that I'm sideloading into bigquery via the [dbt-external-tables](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt-external-tables) module.

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: my_schema
    database: my_project
    loader: gcloud storage

    tables:
      - name: my_table_raw
        description: "external table of reports"
        external:
          location: 'gs://my_bucket/my_reports/*'
          auto_refresh: false
          options:
            format: csv
            skip_leading_rows: 1
```

Everything with this setup is fine so far, data imports correctly, queryable etc.

My simple addition: what is the simplest way to append the file name as a column?

I've attempted something to the effect of:

```
   - name: file_name_column
       expression: metadata$filename
       data_type: string
       description: "the source file name from within gcp"
```

But it looks like bigquery / the module is looking to match the number of columns on the table with the number of columns in the files because I am able to "create" the table in bigquery but get all kinds of errors when I query against it.

Update: from what I see here - the "metadata" expression that I've seen and am trying to use above is snowflake specific. [Source link](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/fishtown-analytics/dbt-external-tables/28/760835914).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand it, all BigQuery external tables pointing to Cloud Storage data have an additional pseudo-column `_FILE_NAME` ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage#the_file_name_pseudo_column)). There's no need to include it in your external table definition, you can simply query it downstream:

```sql
select *,
  _file_name as filename

from {{ source('my_schema', 'my_table_raw') }}
```

The pseudo-column approach is comparable to Snowflake's `metadata$filename` and Redshift's `$path`.

Comment: As C3P0 says, "Thank the maker!"

Comment: Is there any option to change the csv delimiter as well?

Comment: Absolutely! The `dbt-external-tables` YAML spec is really just a passthrough for BigQuery's `create external table` DDL. In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#create_external_table_statement), it looks like `field_delimiter` is supported as one of the `options`. So your YAML `options` dict could include `field_delimiter` alongside `format` and `skip_leading_rows`.