# How to upload csv data that contains newline with dbt

Tags: csv, google-bigquery, dbt

I have a 3rd party generated CSV file that I wish to upload to Google BigQuery using `dbt seed`.

I manage to upload it manually to BigQuery, but I need to enable "Quoted newlines" which is off by default.

When I run `dbt seed`, I get the following error:

```
16:34:43  Runtime Error in seed clickup_task (data/clickup_task.csv)
16:34:43    Error while reading data, error message: CSV table references column position 31, but line starting at position:304 contains only 4 columns.
```

There are 32 columns in the CSV. The file contains column values with newlines. I guess that's where the dbt parser fails. I checked the [dbt seed configuration options](https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/seed-configs), but I haven't found anything relevant.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know - the seed feature is very limited by what is built into dbt-core. So seeds is not the way that I go here. You can see the history of requests for the expansion of seed options [here](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues?q=is%3Aissue+seed) on the dbt-cre issues repo (including my own request for similar optionality [#3990](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/issues/3990) ) but I have to see any real traction on this.

---

That said, what has worked very well for me is to store flat files within the gcp project in a gcs bucket and then utilize the [dbt-external-tables](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables) package for very similar but much more robust file structuring. Managing this can be a lot of overhead I know but becomes very very worth it if your seed files continue expanding in a way that can take advantage of partitioning for instance.

And more importantly - as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67527388/bigquery-dbt-external-tables-external-data-configuration) from Jeremy on stackoverflow,

> The `dbt-external-tables` package supports passing a dictionary of [options](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-external-tables/blob/64b4714ac47abd7cae6c8c400fd5de79f0e13f46/sample_sources/bigquery.yml#L13) for BigQuery external tables, which maps to the [options documented here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#external_table_option_list).

Which for your case, should be either the `quote` or `allowQuotedNewlines` options. If you did choose to use `dbt-external-tables` your source.yml for this would look something like:

`gcs.yml`

```
version: 2

sources:
  - name: clickup
    database: external_tables
    loader: gcloud storage
  
    tables:
      - name: task
        description: "External table of Snowplow events, stored as CSV files in Cloud Storage"
        external:
          location: 'gs://bucket/clickup/task/*'
          options:
            format: csv
            skip_leading_rows: 1
            quote: "\""
            allow_quoted_newlines: true
```

Or something very similar.
And if you end up taking this path and storing task data on a daily partition like, `tasks_2022_04_16.csv`  - you can access that file name and other metadata the provided pseudocolumns also shared with me by Jeremy here:

[Retrieve "filename" from gcp storage during dbt-external-tables sideload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66143582/retrieve-filename-from-gcp-storage-during-dbt-external-tables-sideload/66153656#66153656)

I find it to be a *very* powerful set of tools for files specifically with BigQuery.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your suggestion!

Comment: Sorry sgoley, I've just seen that I cannot give you the bounty any more. I was on away from computer (vacation), and I wasn't aware that the bounty will expire. What a shame!

Comment: All good! Happy to just have answered the question.